# Salesforce SOQL query to retrieve related accounts for an contact

Tags: salesforce, soql

I would like to retrieve the related account for an contact resource from saleforce API. I have tried the below query to retrieve account which has contact Id. But not able to get my requirement.

```
SELECT+Id,Name+from+Contact+where+Id+IN+(SELECT+AccountId+FROM+Contact+where+Email='xxx@gmail.com')
```

Anyone , please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to correlate Id from Contact object and Id from Account object. You can use the relations :

```
select account.name, account.id from contact where email='xxx@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve Account for Contact. You have Email id based on you want Account details.

If you want to Account id then use AccountID field also in your Query:
Your query will like this:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [Select id, name, AccountID
                       from contact where Email = 'test@gmail.com'];

for(Contact con : contactList) {
    System.debug('Account id : ' + con.AccountID);
}
```